# mysql limit in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Say i have this table fields:

```
Field1  Field2 Field3
a       1      1
a       1      2
a       1      3
a       1      4
a       2      1
a       2      2
a       2      3
a       3      1
b       1      1
b       1      2
b       1      3
b       2      1
c       1      1
```

and say i need to group by Field1 (because i need to some calucation on the data),
is there a way to retrive only the first 2 elements grouped by Field2 (sorted desc)?

So for this example i'd like to retrive:

```
a,3,1
a,2,3
a,2,2
a,1,4
a,1,3
b,1,2
b,1,1
b,2,1
c,1,1
```

would be something like

```
SELECT field1, 
       Sum(field2), 
       Sum(field3) 
FROM   table t1 
WHERE  t1.Field1 IN (SELECT t2.Field1 
                     FROM   table t2 
                     WHERE  t2.Field1 = t1.Field1 
                     ORDER  BY Field2, 
                               Field3 DESC 
                     LIMIT  2) 
GROUP  BY field1
```

Comment: What version of MySql are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: I am on version 5.7.18

Comment: Are you sure you want `Sum(field2)`? The value is repeated.

Comment: @renemarxis Then check the link give in the comment immediately above your comment.  Or upgrade to MySQL 8+ and use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way to handle this if you are using MySQL 8+ or later is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1, Field2 ORDER BY Field3 DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY Field1, Field2 DESC, Field3;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you are *not* using MySQL 8+, then this problem gets fairly hairy, fairly quickly.  The best way to do this in MySQL 5.7 or earlier would be to use session variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER`.  But, this requires some verbose code.  You could also try to isolate the top two entries per group, but that two would take some verbose code.  Really, if you have a long term need to run queries like this, then consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: FWIW, I think the 5.7 query is the same character length as the 8.0 query

Answer (score 1):

#### Pre MySQL 8.0 solution:

List only the last two values per `(Field1, Field2)` group:

```
select *
from test t
where t.Field3 >= coalesce((
  select t1.Field3
  from test t1
  where t1.Field1 = t.Field1
    and t1.Field2 = t.Field2
  order by t1.Field3 desc
  limit 1
  offset 1
), 0)
order by Field1, Field2, Field3;
```

Result:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
a       1       3
a       1       4
a       2       2
a       2       3
a       3       1
b       1       2
b       1       3
b       2       1
c       1       1
```

Get SUMs per `Field1` group:

```
select t.Field1
     , sum(Field2)
     , sum(Field3)
from test t
where t.Field3 >= coalesce((
  select t1.Field3
  from test t1
  where t1.Field1 = t.Field1
    and t1.Field2 = t.Field2
  order by t1.Field3 desc
  limit 1
  offset 1
), 0)
group by t.Field1
```

Result:

```
Field1  sum(Field2)     sum(Field3)
a       9               13
b       4               6
c       1               1
```

[Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mp6VxzxtNc1kQXfz3szgeG/0)

Note: this works fine, when the combination of `(Filed1, Filed2, Filed3)` is UNIQUE. If `Field3` can be duplicated within a `(Field1, Field2)` group, we would need more complex logic to limit the result to two rows per group.